# Como passar efeito de Corner Blob para lado direito da tela?

Tags: javascript, html, funções, canvas, fórmula

Eu gostaria de inverter o efeito demonstrado, o fazendo começar do lado direito da tela e se expandindo para o lado esquerdo, entretanto, não consegui isso. Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?
[image: Efeito de Corner Blob]

```js
const SCALE = 0.25;
const TWO_PI = Math.PI * 2;
const HALF_PI = Math.PI / 2;
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const c = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

class Blob {
  constructor() {
    this.wobbleIncrement = 0;
    // use this to change the size of the blob
    this.radius = 500;
    // think of this as detail level
    // number of conections in the `bezierSkin`
    this.segments = 12;
    this.step = HALF_PI / this.segments;
    this.anchors = [];
    this.radii = [];
    this.thetaOff = [];

    const bumpRadius = 100;
    const halfBumpRadius = bumpRadius / 2;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.segments + 2; i++) {
      this.anchors.push(0, 0);
      this.radii.push(Math.random() * bumpRadius - halfBumpRadius);
      this.thetaOff.push(Math.random() * TWO_PI);
    }

    this.theta = 0;
    this.thetaRamp = 0;
    this.thetaRampDest = 12;
    this.rampDamp = 25;
  }
  update() {
    this.thetaRamp += (this.thetaRampDest - this.thetaRamp) / this.rampDamp;
    this.theta += 0.03;

    this.anchors = [0, this.radius];
    for (let i = 0; i <= this.segments + 2; i++) {
      const sine = Math.sin(this.thetaOff[i] + this.theta + this.thetaRamp);
      const rad = this.radius + this.radii[i] * sine;
      const theta = this.step * i;
      const x = rad * Math.sin(theta);
      const y = rad * Math.cos(theta);
      this.anchors.push(x, y);
    }

    c.save();
    c.translate(-10, -10);
    c.scale(SCALE, SCALE);
    c.fillStyle = "blue";
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(0, 0);
    bezierSkin(this.anchors, false);
    c.lineTo(0, 0);
    c.fill();
    c.restore();
  }
}

const blob = new Blob();

function loop() {
  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  blob.update();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
loop();

// array of xy coords, closed boolean
function bezierSkin(bez, closed = true) {
  const avg = calcAvgs(bez);
  const leng = bez.length;

  if (closed) {
    c.moveTo(avg[0], avg[1]);
    for (let i = 2; i < leng; i += 2) {
      let n = i + 1;
      c.quadraticCurveTo(bez[i], bez[n], avg[i], avg[n]);
    }
    c.quadraticCurveTo(bez[0], bez[1], avg[0], avg[1]);
  } else {
    c.moveTo(bez[0], bez[1]);
    c.lineTo(avg[0], avg[1]);
    for (let i = 2; i < leng - 2; i += 2) {
      let n = i + 1;
      c.quadraticCurveTo(bez[i], bez[n], avg[i], avg[n]);
    }
    c.lineTo(bez[leng - 2], bez[leng - 1]);
  }
}

// create anchor points by averaging the control points
function calcAvgs(p) {
  const avg = [];
  const leng = p.length;
  let prev;

  for (let i = 2; i < leng; i++) {
    prev = i - 2;
    avg.push((p[prev] + p[i]) / 2);
  }
  // close
  avg.push((p[0] + p[leng - 2]) / 2, (p[1] + p[leng - 1]) / 2);
  return avg;
}
```

[Corner Blob in Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/ZevanRosser/pen/bde8e879b344202cf06379e44f9e80b2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicamente é só incluir a linha `canvas.style.transform = "scaleX(-1)";` no início do código onde define a altura e largura do canvas.

Pelo que vi o `canvas` só está nessa posição pq é o ponto inicial do *flow-content*, `x=0 y=0`, ou seja, canto superior esquerdo...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O ajuste que fiz é basicamente CSS, não tem mistério, o resultado está abaixo, deixei comentado

```js
const TWO_PI = Math.PI * 2;
const HALF_PI = Math.PI / 2;
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const c = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

// estilo que inverte a posição do canvas para a direita
canvas.style.transform = "scaleX(-1)";

document.body.appendChild(canvas);

class Blob {
  constructor() {
    this.wobbleIncrement = 0;
    // use this to change the size of the blob
    this.radius = 500;
    // think of this as detail level
    // number of conections in the `bezierSkin`
    this.segments = 12;
    this.step = HALF_PI / this.segments;
    this.anchors = [];
    this.radii = [];
    this.thetaOff = [];

    const bumpRadius = 100;
    const halfBumpRadius = bumpRadius / 2;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.segments + 2; i++) {
      this.anchors.push(0, 0);
      this.radii.push(Math.random() * bumpRadius - halfBumpRadius);
      this.thetaOff.push(Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI);
    }

    this.theta = 0;
    this.thetaRamp = 0;
    this.thetaRampDest = 12;
    this.rampDamp = 25;
  }
  update() {
    this.thetaRamp += (this.thetaRampDest - this.thetaRamp) / this.rampDamp;
    this.theta += 0.03;

    this.anchors = [0, this.radius];
    for (let i = 0; i <= this.segments + 2; i++) {
      const sine = Math.sin(this.thetaOff[i] + this.theta + this.thetaRamp);
      const rad = this.radius + this.radii[i] * sine;
      const x = rad * Math.sin(this.step * i);
      const y = rad * Math.cos(this.step * i);
      this.anchors.push(x, y);
    }

    c.save();
    c.translate(-10, -10);
    c.scale(0.5, 0.5);
    c.fillStyle = "blue";
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(0, 0);
    bezierSkin(this.anchors, false);

    c.lineTo(0, 0);
    c.fill();
    c.restore();
  }}


const blob = new Blob();

function loop() {
  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  blob.update();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
loop();

// array of xy coords, closed boolean
function bezierSkin(bez, closed = true) {
  const avg = calcAvgs(bez);
  const leng = bez.length;

  if (closed) {
    c.moveTo(avg[0], avg[1]);
    for (let i = 2; i < leng; i += 2) {
      let n = i + 1;
      c.quadraticCurveTo(bez[i], bez[n], avg[i], avg[n]);
    }
    c.quadraticCurveTo(bez[0], bez[1], avg[0], avg[1]);
  } else {
    c.moveTo(bez[0], bez[1]);
    c.lineTo(avg[0], avg[1]);
    for (let i = 2; i < leng - 2; i += 2) {
      let n = i + 1;
      c.quadraticCurveTo(bez[i], bez[n], avg[i], avg[n]);
    }
    c.lineTo(bez[leng - 2], bez[leng - 1]);
  }
}

// create anchor points by averaging the control points
function calcAvgs(p) {
  const avg = [];
  const leng = p.length;
  let prev;

  for (let i = 2; i < leng; i++) {
    prev = i - 2;
    avg.push((p[prev] + p[i]) / 2);
  }
  // close
  avg.push((p[0] + p[leng - 2]) / 2, (p[1] + p[leng - 1]) / 2);
  return avg;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Olha aqui é outro exemplo tá, mais o importante é a lógica

```
"use strict";

var Test = {
 canvas: undefined,
 canvasContext: undefined,
 rectanglePosition: 0
};
var i = 0; //"Localização" atual do quadrado
var direction = 1; //1 Se a div se mover para a direita, -1 Se a div se mover para esquerda

Test.start = function() {
 Test.canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 Test.canvasContext = 
 Test.canvas.getContext("2d");
 Test.mainLoop();
};
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', Test.start);
Test.update = function() {
 //var d = new Date();
 //Test.rectanglePosition = d.getTime() % Test.canvas.width;
 if (i <= 0) {
  direction = 1;
 } 
 else if (i >= (Test.canvas.width - 50)) {
  //Text.canvas.width - 50 é até onde o quadrado pode ir
  //Para a direita sem tirar o quadrado da tela
  //(Já que 50 é a largura do quadrado)
  direction = -1;
 }
 i += direction;
 Test.rectanglePosition = i;
};
Test.draw = function() {
 Test.canvasContext.fillStyle = "green";   
 Test.canvasContext.fillRect(Test.rectanglePosition, 100, 50, 50);
};
Test.mainLoop = function() {
 Test.clearCanvas();
 Test.update();
 Test.draw();
 window.setTimeout(Test.mainLoop, 1000 / 60);
};
Test.clearCanvas = function() {
 Test.canvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, Test.canvas.width, Test.canvas.height);
};
```

É outro exemplo mais não tem muita importância, é só ajustar, só pegar o exemplo, e ir modificando e testando, a explicação está nos comentários do códico, ele é simples não tem muito o que explicar, é isso, tá ae a resposta vlw :)

**Códico online:**

> https://codepen.io/Maria_eduarda/pen/GRNoVbv